# Failed to implement TTS on Android wear Emulator

Tags: android, wear-os, text-to-speech, android-wear-2.0

I'm trying to copy my working TTS service code from app code to wear code but not work.

```
public class VoiceService extends Service implements 
TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener {

private final String TAG = "VoiceService";

private final int LONG_DURATION = 5000;
private final int SHORT_DURATION = 1200;

private TextToSpeech mTts;
private String messageTitle;
private String messageContext;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
    try{
        mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        mTts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    messageTitle = ...
    messageContext = ...
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onInit & status = " + status);
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
        int result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
        Log.i(TAG, "TextToSpeech.SUCCESS");
        if (result != TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                && result != TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED
                && messageTitle.length() > 0
                ) {
            Log.i(TAG, "messageTitle.length() > 0");
            ...
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onUtteranceCompleted(String uttId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onUtteranceCompleted");
    messageTitle = "";
    messageContext = "";
    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");
    // Text to Speech engine was attached
    if (mTts != null) {
        mTts.stop();
        mTts.shutdown();
        mTts = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

...
}
```

The log is simply as follows:

```
I/VoiceService: onCreate
I/VoiceService: onInit & status = -1
I/VoiceService: onStartCommand
```

I do not understand why onInit comes before onStartCommand, and failed, and the service stuck there forever...

I followed some threads and run the following code in mainactivity:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent installIntent = new Intent();
installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = pm.resolveActivity( installIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY );

if( resolveInfo == null ) {
    // Not able to find he activity which should be started for this intent
    Log.i(TAG, "Not able to find the activity which should be started for this intent");
} else {
    Log.i(TAG, "try to install...");
    startActivity( installIntent );
}
```

The log was as follow and I do not have idea to fix it:

> Not able to find the activity which should be started for this intent

I am using Android Wear Emulator and I could not find TTS Enable button in Setting -> Accessibility menu. But under the menu, I found TalkBack(experimental), no idea what it is.

I had spent few days in this. a bit tired tonight. Please give me some direction of how to make TTS works in emulator.

Comment: what happens if you test with a real device?

Comment: well, i do not have one at the moment and in order to verify it, i have just ordered one and shall ship to me next next week. but then, in the meantime, is there anything i can do?

Comment: My nixon mission does not have tts. I read it was coming generally for wear 2.0 but no luck with me. Maybe some on the watches with speakers implemented it. Will be interested to see what you find with yours.

Comment: oh dear, my device has just arrived and same result to emulator....i feel so upset at the moment. I have to keep looking and maybe you are right about watches with speakers implementing TTS since my watch is LG Style.